# Why does React Dev Tools profiler show me two "AppContainers"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-devtools, react-native-debugger

React dev tools profiler has started showing me two "AppContainers", whereas before I did not see one, or have any option to choose one. By selecting either one, I get different profiling data:

What do they represent and how can I go back to not having to choice between choosing one?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have the app/instance running in multiple instances.
Say a browser(tab) and one on phone (thus the reason for multiple containers which shows different profiles)

The solution to only getting one instance would be to stop/run only at one instance.

(Sidenote: With the limited information provided this is all I could think of/speculate)